Development details of the Hungarian algorithm for Maximum Perfect Bipartite Matching
There are two realization forms of Hungarian algorithm. One is the original dynamic matrix, and the other is via equality subgraph. I just checked the original paper of Hungarian method by Kuhn, which adopts the dynamic matrix. As is told by Wiki, James Munkres reviewed the algorithm in 1957 and observed that it is strongly polynomial.
However, I am confused about the following.

Who invented the equality subgraph? It is another popular realization of Hungarian algorithm, and simpler.

The Hungarian algorithm is also called Munkres' assignment algorithm. Is that just because he proved a better time complexity?


